# Tricky projectile motion problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile

Two robbers one on the ground one on roof, point their guns at each other at fire simultaneously. Show that their bullets will collide unless the calculated collision point is underground, which is not allowed. The guy on the ground fires with a velocity v1 and the other at a velocity v2, show that the condition for colliding is v1+v2 > gd/v1sin(2Q) where g is 9.81ms^-2 and d is the horizontal between the two and Q is the angle of elevation of the line joining the two robbers=9.81ms^-2 and Y(t) and X(t) is the motion of the robber on the roof whilst y(t) and x(t) are the robbers on the grounds far all I have determined is the equations of motion for the two and that is as follows. It is trivial that y(t)=v1sin(Q)t -gt^2/2 and that x(t)=v2cos(Q)t. Now the angle that is anticlockwise from the negative horizontal of the robber is 90 - Q using basic trigonometry, using this we can determine that the velocity projected onto the plane will be the negative magnitude of v2cos(90 - Q)=v2sin(Q) similar logic is used to show that the projection on the x plane is -v2cos(Q) therefore I end up with $$X(t)=-v2cos(Q)t + d, Y(t)=-v2sin(Q)t (-gt^2)/2 .$$ From here I have just been fidgeting with concepts and equations and have made no progress in showing that the inequality is true help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are making this way to difficult.  Let's ignore gravity for a moment.  In this case it is easy to see that if two guns are pointed directly at each other the bullets will collide.  The speed of the bullets from each gun will be factor in where they collide, but the respective bullet speeds play no role in the fact that they will collide.  They will head directly toward each other and at some point they will hit each other.  Now, let's add gravity.  The only thing that changes is that each bullet is falling with a constant acceleration of 9.8 meters per second squared.  Both bullets will travel for exactly the same period of time regardless of their velocities.  That is, they were shot at the same time and the moment of impact is the same for both; therefore, the time interval for both is identical.  Since both bullets accelerate toward the surface at the same rate and the time interval is identical for both, they will, once again, collide with each other.